# what kind of claims based authentications we can use in SharePoint 2010

Tags: authentication, claims

Hi I have seen lot of different scenarios on googling for claims based authentication. What sort of different authentications can we use for SharePoint 2010 and how to determine which one to go for. Can some one elaborate on this am confused on this. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Their are 3 differnt way to implement the claims authentication.

**Windows authentication methods**

- NTLM
- Kerberos
- Anonymous
- Basic
- Digest

**Forms-based authentication methods**

- LDAP
- SQL Server database or other database
- Custom or third-party membership and role providers

**SAML token-based authentication methods**

- AD FS 2.0
- Third-party identity provider
- LDAP

Choosing which type of  claims-based authentication should be based on business needs. For example, if you need to support user accounts in identity providers that are not based on Active Directory Domain Services (AD DS), and you implement forms-based authentication, you must use forms-based authentication with claims-based authentication in SharePoint Foundation 2010. We recommend that you use claims-based authentication whenever possible.

Read more over here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee782549(v=office.14).aspx